# Populate 3rd model in Sailsjs and Waterline

Tags: associations, sails.js, waterline

Say I have three models:

```
user
projects
files
```

User has many projects and project has many files. If I run the following in console:

```
User.find().populate('projects').exec(function(err,r){console.log(r[0].toJSON())});
```

I will see all projects but no files within projects. Is it possible to populate files as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is currently not supported.

See this thread. https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/256